# Don't trigger the frame-killer on google results?

Tags: feature-request, google, search

When you [google search for images](http://www.google.com.mx/search?hl=en&q=site:meta.stackoverflow.com%20bug&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch), if you click to preview any image, you will see this alert:

[image]

Is there any way this frame-killer excludes google somehow?

Comment: Also on Google Translate.

Comment: Sounds more like a bug in Google, they shouldn't use iframe for the preview.